# How to describe type of job formally?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a formal documents for describe health status according to type of job. I want to compare office workers and blue collar worker (non office worker) but I am confused what is the formal word of "blue collar workers" for documents.

Could I just use blue collar workers or non office workers? or There were better words for me.

Comment: "Blue collar workers" is an acceptable term in most contexts.

Comment: This depends on where you are and what kind of company. Different terms are likely in a corporation vs. a small company, for example. Without more specifics you will only get opinions that might be OK.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the kind of formal document that you're writing? Is it a scientific journal paper, a questionnaire, a policy manual, a medical report, etc.?

Comment: Thank you for answer to my questions. My document is actually scientific journal for my degree. I want to compare mental/physical health status between office worker and blue collar worker.

Comment: Blue collar and white collar is fine in the USA. It has little or no meaning in the UK though. Kind of like "black hat" and "white hat" means nothing to us Brits.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a *policy* manual, workers are usually divided into groups which may be

> **full time staff**
>   **part time staff**
>   **contractors**
>   **line management**
>   **middle management**
>   **upper management**
>   **board members**

**Blue collar workers** are usually **staff** and not **management**.